# emitting a nodejs event when an event on google calendar is added or updated

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Is this possible to emit a nodejs event when a Google calendar event is added or modified? On my nodejs server, I can get/list all the events on the calendar. But I would like to retrieve the events based on the nodejs event rather than checking it manually after a regular interval. Appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Can you show some code of how you get the events data?

Comment: @Dejan you can check step 3 here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Something like that would require Google to *know* about *your* app (to send events or push data to). Google's APIs is only for meant to *be* accessed. It cannot "tell" your app anything. Your app has to be the one that "asks" Google whether or not something it wants exists or has happened.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is possible, as stated here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push

You can register a callback URL so you app receives information when your event changes or gets modified. With the Node.JS API it's something like:

```
  calendar.events.watch({

        auth:jwtClient,
        resource: {
            id: "yourChannelId",
            type: 'web_hook',
            address: "https://www.yoursite.com/notifications"
        },
        calendarId: "yourcalendarId"
    }, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
        console.log(response);

    });
```